# Getting the "Submit" button to disappear after it's clicked

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webforms

This is my Web form from Visual Studio.  After the user clicks the "Submit" button, another view displays, thanking them for filling out the form, but the button still shows on the page with the thank you message.  How do I make it disappear after it's clicked?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HelloWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.HelloWebForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 37px">
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelNameForm" runat="server" Width="502px">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:Label ID="LabelAddr1" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAddr1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelAddr2" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            City<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAddr2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            State<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            Zip<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Phone Number<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            email<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            Age<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">0-17</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">18-21</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">22-25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">26-35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">36+</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="407px">
                Gender<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Male">Male</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Female">Female</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                Favorite Cheese<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                How often do you eat cheese? (Check one)<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>Every Day</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Every Other Day</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Once A Week</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>I Don&#39;t Like Cheese</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                Cheese Texture Preferences (Check All That Apply)<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Hard</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Semi-hard</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Semi-soft</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Soft</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Crumbly</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                Milk Type Preferences (Check All That Apply)<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Buffalo</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Cow</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Goat</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Vegetarian</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelThankYou" runat="server" Width="442px">
            Thank you for taking the survey, <asp:Label ID="LabelThankYouName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add the button to the PanelNameForm and then you could hide the whole panel once you click on it. On the Onclick_button event add.

```
PanelThankYou.Visible = true
PanelNameForm.Visible = false
```

Comment: Thank you to all who responded.  All of the suggestions were very helpful, but I went with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary a normal practice is to redirect to a separate "Thank You" page upon form submit.

In your case you can simple add

```
Button.Visible = False
```

Into Button's click event. (btw, you may want to change ID of the button to something different from the reserved word).

Answer (score 0):

set autopostback=true in your design code,

then in your code behind class file check for ispagepostback property if its true submit say thanks n load new page or hide the thank you message..